# Jackson - Working with arrays of objects, appending and removing

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I'm working with the Jackson API in Java for dealing with JSON. I've been working with it a bit here and there, but nothing too in-depth.

Currently, I'm looking for a good way to take an array of JSON objects (either via a stream or String) that was created from a list of POJOs and append or remove a POJO. In the case of appending, duplicate checking isn't really necessary. As a simple example, let's say I have this array built from a list of Java objects with a single variable named "field":

```
[{"field":"value"},{"field":"value2"}]
```

And I'd like to append an object of the same type with "field" set to "value3". I could simply deserialize the whole array into a List of Java Objects, add the new object, then serialize it back into JSON, but that feels like overkill. It would be better if I could use Jackson to simply serialize the new object and append it to the end of the JSON array. The same would apply to removing an existing object from the array.

Comment: Bit of a moot question. Do you use jackson to append it as an object or just edit the string? Personally I would stick with jackson instead of combining the two. its quick

Comment: I'm not trying to manipulate the String directly. I've been digging through some of the Jackson documentation, but there's quite a bit to go through and I have yet to find out how to perform this operation directly with Jackson. Ideally, I could wrap an InputStream with Jackson and write it directly to an OutputStream, either adding the new object at the end or removing an existing object as the JSON passes between streams.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way, but strangely, it's over twice as slow as the direct deserialize-add-reserialze method with a list of 500 POJOs that have three fields each, and it only gets worse with more objects.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonParser parser = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(input);
JsonGenerator gen = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(output, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
gen.writeStartArray();
parser.nextToken();
while (parser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    //gen.writeTree(parser.readValueAsTree());
    //parser.skipChildren();
    //EDIT: This is much faster as the only method in the loop:
    gen.copyCurrentStructure(parser);
}
gen.writeTree(mapper.valueToTree(/*new Object to add*/);
gen.writeEndArray();
gen.close();
parser.close();
```

Even if I don't get each object as a tree and instead move them iteratively as fields/values, it's a bit faster, but still considerably slower than the alternative. Is this to be expected or is there a better way to handle it as streaming data rather than the bulk JSON-to-Java-to-JSON method?

EDIT: AHA! Found that the JsonGenerator can directly copy the current structure from a JsonParser with`copyCurrentStructure(JsonParser)`. Using this in the while loop is faster and now outruns the bruteforce method by a considerable amount.

Comment: Yes, there is some hidden overhead when doing value conversions (to/from tree or POJO); so direct copying from `JsonParser` to `JsonGeneraror` is more efficient. This is why either your original idea (read into a `List`, append, write), or going low-level with Streaming API are the best approaches.